# Encode expression into a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

I have an expression of the form:

$$c {\partial^{k+l} \Phi(\theta,\phi,n) \over \partial \theta^k \partial \phi^l}$$

$n,k,l$ are (positive) integers. $c$ is some constant. It is also possible that $c$ appears by itself. I would like a function, `myExprToList` that takes such an expression as input and outputs in an array: `{c,k,l,n}`, or just `{c}` if the constant is by itself.

As an example, suppose I have the two expressions:

```
expr1 = 42 D[D[\[CapitalPhi][\[Theta], \[Phi], 10], {\[Theta], 2}], {\[Phi], 3}]
expr2 = -1
```

I would then want respectively:

```
 myExprToList[expr1] (* Out: {42,2,3,10} *)
 myExprToList[expr2] (* Out: {-1} *)
```

My first instinct was to use the function `PolynomialRemainder`, but since the $k,l,n$ are a prior unknown, I would need to use patterns and I am not sure how this would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work, also for c=1 :

```
myExprToList[
  c_.  Derivative[k_, l_, _][_][_, _, n_]
]:= {c, k, l, n};
myExprToList[c_. ] := {c};
```

Comment: Pretty good. It fails however if $c=1$ or if the function is undifferentiated.

Comment: There will also need to be a case needed for when the function appears undifferentiated

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using a pattern:

```
pat=c_ D[D[\[CapitalPhi][\[Theta], \[Phi], n_ : 0], {\[Theta], 
     l_ : 0}], {\[Phi], k_ : 0}] -> {c, k, l, n}
```

Then the examples:

```
expr1 = 42 D[D[\[CapitalPhi][\[Theta], \[Phi], 10], {\[Theta], 2}], {\[Phi], 3}];
expr2 = -1;

expr1 /. pat
(*{42, 3, 2, 10}*)

expr2 /. pat
(* -1 *)
```

Comment: This does not work if c=1 or if the function appears undifferentiated.

Comment: To make it work for c=1 give a default value to c: `c_:1`

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[exprToList]

exprToList[expr_, headparts_: {1, 2}, argparts_: {3}] := 
 expr /. a_. Derivative[b__][_][c__] :> Flatten[{a, {b}[[headparts]], {c}[[argparts]]}]
```

***Examples:***

```
expr1 = 42 D[D[Φ[θ, ϕ, 10], {θ, 2}], {ϕ, 3}]
```

[image]

Extract parameters `{1, 2}` from the operator head and part `{3}` from the arguments (default):

```
exprToList @ expr1
```

> ```
> {42, 2, 3, 10}
> ```

Extract parameters `{1, 3}` from the operator head and parts `{1, 2, 3}` from the arguments:

```
exprToList[expr1, {1, 3}, All]
```

> ```
> {42, 2, 0, θ, ϕ, 10}
> ```

```
expr2 = D[D[Φ[θ, ϕ, 10], {θ, 2}], {ϕ, 3}]
```

[image]

```
exprToList @ expr2
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 10}
> ```

```
expr3 = 500 Derivative[3, 1, 2, 2, 1][Φ][θ, ϕ, ψ, λ, ρ]
```

[image]

```
exprToList[expr3, All, All]
```

> ```
> {500, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, θ, ϕ, ψ, λ, ρ}
> ```

```
expr4 = -1

exprToList @ expr4
```

> ```
> -1
> ```

Comment: Does not work if function is undifferentiated